# Create X509Certificate From Base64 Encoded DER

Tags: c#, itext, bouncycastle

I have a base64 encoded DER string (I am not sure because web service is not well documented. However I guess because I can parse with [asn decoder](https://holtstrom.com/michael/tools/asn1decoder.php)). When I try create X509Certificate2 with following code

```
string base64str = "MHExNTAzBgNVBAMMLFR1cmtjZWxsIE1vYmlsIE5FUyBIaXptZXQgU2HEn2xhecSxY8Sxc8SxIFM3MSswKQYDVQQKDCJFbGVrdHJvbmlrIEJpbGdpIEfDvHZlbmxpxJ9pIEEuxZ4uMQswCQYDVQQGEwJUUg==";

var x509cert = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64str)));
```

I got belowed exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cannot
> find the requested object.'

What I am missing?

Comment: That Base64 string does not represent a valid certificate.

Comment: It's DER encoded ASN.1 but it's not a certificate. It appears to be just one of the names in a certificate, perhaps the issuer name.

Comment: Actually I want to use this ASN.1 for pdf signing with iText thus I need to generate chain from that. But I don't know how to use that.

Comment: *"Actually I want to use this ASN.1 for pdf signing with iText"* - as @Presi has indicated, what you have is just a tiny part of a certificate. For signing you'll need the full certificate and (direct or indirect) access to the private key.